# Copy text from within the batch file to a new text file

Tags: windows

I am trying to copy the line below to a new text file using a batch file. The line is given below:

```
objIEA.Navigate "http://"&WScript.Arguments(0)&"/video?session=3&alphabet=83&channel="&WScript.Arguments(1)&"&profile="& WScript.Arguments(2)
```

What I did is something like this and I am getting an error while executing the batch file.

```
ECHO objIEA.Navigate "http://"&WScript.Arguments(0)&"/video?session=3&alphabet=83&channel="&WScript.Arguments(1)&"&profile="& WScript.Arguments(2) > test.txt
```

The new file will have a `.vbs` extension, but it is not even working for `test.txt`.

Comment: terrible, you should've done a bit of troubleshooting to narrow it down, then you'd have seen it was the ampersands that were the issue, and you could've asked it in simpler form with a clearer example focusing on the ampersands. very poor work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the ampersands that are causing the problem (they're interpreted as special characters)

You can escape these out with the caret '^'

e.g. this works:

```
ECHO objIEA.Navigate "http://"^&WScript.Arguments(0)^&"/video?session=3&alphabet=83&channel="^&WScript.Arguments(1)^&"^&profile="^& WScript.Arguments(2) > test.txt
```